# How do I save static strings to an XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, string, unity-game-engine, serialization

I am trying to save multiple static strings to an XML file, but all the tutorials I looked at didn't show how to save strings - let alone static ones.

It doesn't help that I don't know the first thing about coding in C#.

```
public class Strings
{
  public static string string1 = "text1";
  public static string string2 = "text2";
  public static string string3 = "text3";
//I am dealing with way more than 3 strings, but I don't want to type out all of them
}
```

How would I collect these strings, and then save them as an XML file?
I am thinking that something like this might work, but I doubt that it would

```
public class StringSaver
{
  foreach (static string in Strings)
  {
   savestring1 = Strings.string1;
   savestring2 = Strings.string2;
   savestring3 = Strings.string3;
  }

}

public class StringXML 
{
  XMLSerializer xmlstringsaver = new XMLSerializer(Typeof(StringSaver));

}
```

What I intend to happen is that the strings get saved to a XML file, and if one or multiple of the strings are changed, I would like the changes to be saved too.
(edit) I am using unity, if that changes anything

Comment: this maybe?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194944/in-c-what-is-the-best-method-to-format-a-string-as-xml

Comment: `let alone static ones` It does not matter if its a static string or not. The value is the same. static string is not some sort of a different object or type. static just means that it relates to itself rather then an instance. In other words, to use the variable, you do not have to create an instance of the class.

Comment: Use IXmlSerializable.  You get a Xmlreader and XmlWriter that you can read/write any type formats.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution but you can save all the static strings into list and then serialize that:

```
List<string> l = new List<string>(); // If you want, you can use Dictionary, but XmlSerializer win't be able to serialize it
foreach (FieldInfo fi in typeof(Strings).GetFields().Where(p => p.IsStatic && (p.FieldType == typeof(string)) /*&& p.IsPublic*/))
    // this will go trough all static strings in Strings, you can uncomment the IsPublic if you want only public ones
{
    l.Add(fi.GetValue(new Strings()) as string); // this will add the value of the current static string to the List
    // in case you would use dictionary aou can use 'fi.Name' (name of the string) as key
}
// now l contains all static strings from Strings class, in the same order in which tey are defined in the Strings class, and you can do with it what you want
// here I serialized it using XmlSerializer
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(l.GetType());
string ser;
using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
{
    s.Serialize(writer, l);
    ser = writer.ToString(); // ser will contain the serialized list
}
```

Keep in mind that you will need to add these references:

```
using System.Collections.Generic; // for List
using System.IO; // for StringWriter
using System.Linq; // for function .Where to query only static strings
using System.Xml.Serialization; // for serialization
using System.Reflection; // for getting all fields from class Strings
```

There is propably much better way to do that (without reflection) but this works without you needing to add all the string to the list manualy.